# xsl loading image to get metadata

Tags: java, xslt, metadata

i would like to load an image to get the metadata. my code is like this :
the value of "url" is like this : "http:\localhost:8080\mypics\pic1.jpg"

```
<xsl:call-template name="mypic">
  <xsl:with-param name="metadata" select="document($url)/metadata"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

i get this exception : ID systÞme inconnu; Ligne #47; Colonne #38; Unable to load the requested document : C:\http:\localhost:8080\mypics\pic1.jpg (the specific path was not found)

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `$url` should be

```
http://localhost:8080/mypics/pic1.jpg
```

**Update**

According to [this documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_document.asp) you need to specify an URI and the resource at that URI has to be of **xml type**. I strongly doubt, that you can handle images with this expression. The `document()` function is used to access (xml-)nodes in external documents.

I guess, the backslashes made the processor believe the string was pointing to a file resource, relative to `C:\`.

Answer (score 0):

> i would like to load an image to get the metadata. my code is like
>   this : the value of "url" is like this :
>   "http:\localhost:8080\mypics\pic1.jpg"

**In XSLT you cant load a file unless it contains a well-formed XML document, or just text** (not binary).

In an XSLT transformation only XML documents (with the `document()` function) or text files (with the XSLT 2.0 `unparsed-text()`) function can be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there is no native XSLT way to do this as I guess Dimitrie would have shown us one if existed.

The alternative is to drop out to Java. Write your own extension function in Java and call it from your XSLT. This link shows how this can be done:

http://www.redstream.nl/2011/03/29/xslt-2-0-and-java-extensions/